# python function using print works return doesnt

Tags: python, printing, return

I've been scanning message boards for hours and still can't figure this one out:
I'm creating a function that outputs correctly when print is used but can't get the same results with return.

```
list=[newport, sebastian, vero]
```

My Function:

```
def email_tides(list):
    for i in list:
        l=i.find('stationname')
        location=l.text
        return location

z=email_tides(list)
print z
```

output:
    NEWPORT

when i replace print with return (and get rid of the z=...) the output is:

```
NEWPORT
Sebastian
Vero Beach
```

I want to be able to return the output that print is giving me.

Comment: `i.find` will return an `int` and an `int` dosen't have a text property, so your code is not valid

Comment: the function is in python and i have not come across .find, edit your post and explain clearly

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the index of list. Right now you are just telling python to return the entire list, you just want to return on thing.

---

For example:

```
return z[0]
```

This will return the string "newport".

Answer (score -1):

Your code doesn't work at all. Couldn't even understand what it's supposed to do.
I would guess that your code returns the first thing that it finds (newport).

When a function returns, it immediately exits and doesn't continue, meaning that you only get the first thing that you return.

I suggest editing your question and make the function email_tides more readable and in proper code format.

Also document the behaviour and expected behaviour better.